# DB2 Query issue with Hibernate when checking for values

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2

I have this query, using Hibernate 4 and DB2, running a native query:

```
select * from TABLE1 t where (:param1 is null or t.NAME = :param1)
```

That throws exception that null is invalid in the context (since SQL becomes select * from TABLE1 t where (null is null or t.NAME = null))

So I tried:

```
select * from TABLE1 t where (COALESCE(:param1,'!') = '!' or t.NAME = :param1)
```

That throws exception when I pass value "JUSTIN"  -

```
"THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER  IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE"
```

Which appears to be cause by the fact that DB2 checks the length of ":param1" against "!".

Is there a way in DB2 to pass dynamic parameters?

I'm starting to hate DB2....

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this works with Hibernate:

```
select * from TABLE1 t where NVL(:param1, t.NAME) = t.NAME;
```